# OpenCV: Multiply Matrix by Constant in range (0,1). How is data handled?

Tags: opencv, matrix, floating-point, char, constants

If I have a matrix

cv::Mat M;

and multiply it by a constant

double c;

using

result=c*A;

where c is between 0 and 1

how is the data handled?  I understand that the data is uchar.  If a pixel value is 26 and c=0.2, would the result be
truncate(26*0.2)=5?

Many thanks in advance,
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to OpenCV [docs](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const), data is converted to double, the needed operations performed on it, then cast to the destination type:

```
dst = (dst_type)((double)src*a+b);
```

where a and b are double constants

Answer (score 1):

1.) data are not necessarily have uchar type.
2.) Yes.You can check it by yourself

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::ones(3 , 1, cv::DataType<unsigned char>::type);
double c = 0.2;
m.at<unsigned char>(0 , 0) = 26;
m.at<unsigned char>(1 , 0) = 27;
m.at<unsigned char>(1 , 0) = 28;
cv::Mat res = c * m;
cout << "res = "<< endl << " "  << res << endl << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In comments for cvDiv I have found following:

```
/* element-wise division/inversion with scaling:
    dst(idx) = src1(idx) * scale / src2(idx)
    or dst(idx) = scale / src2(idx) if src1 == 0 */
CVAPI(void)  cvDiv( const CvArr* src1, const CvArr* src2,
                    CvArr* dst, double scale CV_DEFAULT(1));
```

Probably you can use "scale" parameter as a constant and specify src1 as 0.